# Can you put a spot on a map, and then press that spot to open up a new page on Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I have tried to do this but can not seem to get it to work. I noticed even the standard map in Apple doesn't let you do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with the map is, that is is not interactive. You can add a spot, but not react on user input. If the user taps on the map the built in watch kit map app will be opened.